# Updating item based on linking data in three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Trying to update a field while needing to link three tables, and matching three fields in two of the tables.

I need to update TableB Options by linking the ID to the ID in TableA and matching the list from TableC by matching the Fname,Lname,address fields from TableA.

```
TableA:        TableB:         TableC:
ID             ID
Fname          Options         Fname
Lname                          Lname
address                        address
```

I've tried joins and selects but can't figure out how to join on matching three fields between two tables.  Considered adding an ID field to TableC and first updating the ID field from TableA and then updating TableB, but still can't figure out how to match the three fields.  I don't get all the results returned.

```
select TableB.options, TableA.fname, TableA.lname from TableB inner join TableA on TableB.id = TableA.id inner join TableC on TableA.address = TableC.address where TableA.firstname=TableC.fname and TableA.lname=TableC.lname
```

It did not return the correct number of people (68 instead of 128).

Also tried this which returned the wrong list of people (using a zip field also):

```
Select * from TableB where ID in(Select ID from TableA where Address in(Select Address from TableC) and zip in (Select Zipcode from TableC))
```

Upon further investigation some records will not show because the data will not match, but for those that should match I'd like to update a new ID field in TableC. Tried the following but get an error message that I need an EXISTS:

```
update atblundeliverables set personid= (select id, firstname, lastname from tblpeople where firstname in (select firstname from atblundeliverables where street in (select addressline1 from atblundeliverables)))
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using ? Please add the relevant tag to your question (oracle, mysql, sql-server, ...).

Comment: Please show, what you've tried and what the problem was with that. Also tell how `options`should be changed, i.e. what's the new value it should have after the `UPDATE`.

Comment: To make sure I got the right list of people before trying to update I tried this:

Comment: select TableB.options, TableA.fname, TableA.lname
from TableB
inner join TableA on TableB.id = TableA.id
inner join TableC on TableA.address = TableC.address 
where TableA.firstname=TableC.fname and TableA.lname=TableC.lname            It did not return the correct number of people (68 instead of 128)

Comment: Also tried this which returned the wrong list of people (using a zip field also): Select * from TableB where ID in(Select ID from TableA where Address in(Select Address from TableC) and zip  in (Select Zipcode from TableC))

Comment: Ok - upon further investigation some records will not show because the data will not match.  But for those that should match I'd like to update a new ID field in TableC.  Tried the following but get an error message that I need an EXISTS                                        update atblundeliverables set personid=
(select id, firstname, lastname
from tblpeople where firstname in (select firstname from atblundeliverables 
where street in (select addressline1 from atblundeliverables)))

Answer (score 0):

This update should work.  Try it as Select, with the Where to eliminate Nulls

```
--Update dbo.[Link3_TableB]
--  Set Options = 'doesMATCH'
Select Options
      ,dbo.[Link3_TableB].*
      ,dbo.[Link3_TableA].*
      ,dbo.[Link3_TableC].*
From      dbo.[Link3_TableB]
Left Join dbo.[Link3_TableA]
       On dbo.[Link3_TableB].ID = dbo.[Link3_TableA].ID
Left Join dbo.[Link3_TableC]
       On dbo.[Link3_TableA].Fname   = dbo.[Link3_TableC].Fname
      and dbo.[Link3_TableA].Lname   = dbo.[Link3_TableC].Lname
      and dbo.[Link3_TableA].address = dbo.[Link3_TableC].address
Where Not dbo.[Link3_TableA].ID Is Null  
And   Not dbo.[Link3_TableC].Fname Is Null
```